# App/Views/Pages/used.ctp cannot be read (CAKEPHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Good day!

I have a home page wherein there's a menu at the left side part of it. The button's href when clicked will go to a .ctp file called used.ctp under app/views/pages FOLDER

I already considered putting pages_controller.php and app_controller.php in my app/controllers folder but nothing happened.

The header tag inside the used.ctp cannot be read.

Only the static header declared from index.ctp is all i can see while viewing the used.ctp

First, there was a mysterious error that appeared like...

Error: Create the class controller blah blah blah user_controller.php below the file

Something like that.

I fixed it by creating the said used_controller.php

```
<?php
class UsedController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Used';
}
?>
```

But upon refreshing the used.ctp 
it still appears empty with only the static header on top declared on index.ctp

Please help me. :(

If you want to see the full source code:

Download -> http://www.mediafire.com/?h3sc14gogq9ohtc

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The users.ctp file needs to go in /View/Users and you need to create a method in the controller to link to that view.

So

```
<?php
   class UsedController extends AppController {

      var $name = 'Used';

      public function users() {


    }
}
```

?>

I suggest following a tutorial like the following;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: Im pertaining to used_controller.php

Comment: <?php
   class UsedController extends AppController {

      var $name = 'Used';

      public function used() {


    }
}

?>

didnt work

Comment: Solved already!

Thanks btw!


I just implemented

<?php echo $this->Html->link('Used Equip', 'used', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank')); ?>


instead of the native <a href=""> 


for the link on my menu that will redirect to used.ctp